# Custom font in android application development

Tags: android, fonts

I don't want to use android default font in my android app. I would like to use "Segoe UI Light" font in my android app. how should i write style and theme code for custom font. OR what should i do, if i want to use custom font in android app. Please . . . .

Answer (score 3):

Place whichever font you want in fonts folder in,

res/assets/fonts

Then in in your code,

```
    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");
    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```